# Can I use Selenium IDE and have it use XPath instead of ID by default?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have a situation where the IDs of all elements are unique GUIDs, regenerated on each page load.

So I can't use IDs, although Selenium IDE defaults to IDs for obvious reasons.

My workaround is to record with Selenium IDE, then go back and manually edit the IDs to replace them with the right XPath, but this is really time-consuming.

Is there a way it can be set to use XPaths instead of IDs, by default?

Or is there another similar application/extension which can do this?

Comment: Other than Selenium IDE .You can give try to Playwright inspector https://playwright.dev/docs/inspector/ . It will record the script using css selectors or some pseudo-classes specific to Playwright . Or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/headless-recorder/djeegiggegleadkkbgopoonhjimgehda?hl=en Headless recorder to generate script for Playwright or Puppeteer

Comment: look at this [photo](https://i.postimg.cc/QhzsZxpg/Screenshot-2021-09-13-021855.png), I used XPath on google to type something, did I do anything wrong? If not see [this page](https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-ide-locating-strategies-by-xpath) on how to use XPath with Selenium IDE, but if I'm wrong please enlighten me so I'll be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium IDE/Katalon... recordings can be an OK starting point, depending on who you ask, but you need to go over them.

XPath expressions are specially tricky and often need to be worked on after a recording tool obtains them.

There is no way around this even if you can get the tool you are using to use xpath by default somehow.